# How to solve this cron job error directory not found?

Tags: php, cron, jobs

I have make one cron job as below

```
<?php 
echo "HI";
?>
```

When i ran it using cron job it give me error "?php directory not found"

Please help me regarding this.

Thanks in advance.

Kanji

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you run it as a cron job? Either you need to run it like

```
php my-program.php
```

Or you need to run it directly (without php) and put the following at the top:

```
#!php
```

In the above examples you need to replace `php` by the full path to your php instance, which you can find my typing the following on the shell:

```
which php
```